How to wire two 3 way switches and 3 outlets with one hot wire coming in
I'm working in an 8 by 10 shed with 2 doors. There is one outlet with a shop light with an extension cord plugged into that outlet. I want to put 2 combination boxes (outlets and switch) at both doors and an outlet at top of wall for shop light to plug into. I want both switches to control outlet where shop light plugs in. First I tried light switch to light Switch outlet to outlet hot wire to outlet light switch to outlet for shop light and jumper between switch and outlet At 1 door.
I tried the breaker immediately kicked so I went back. Took the jumper out between light switch and outlet. Tried the breaker, the light came on when I flipped the switch It kicked the breaker now I'm not sure what to do. I am using 12/2 wire. The hot wire is also 12/2 wire.

If you don't know what to do then maybe you're not ready to do this safely by yourself.

Have you tried using google for three way switch circuits?  Three way switch circuits usually easier to see/understand with pictures than words.

3 way circuit looks compliated but it is not.. One ome side you have the inlet, and the outlet on the other side. In between are the switching wires. The outlet side goes to all your lights and plugs,

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post doesn't contain enough detail for anyone to help. You'll need to provide a diagram or clear photos, or a much more specific description.

At a minimum, you're going to need some 12/3 cable between the switches.

Thank you everyone I will Google and get 12/3 wire.

I am concerned for your safety, based on the “wire it and power it and see if the breaker trips” approach.  There are a lot of ways to miswire this that will endanger you without tripping the breaker.   I would be OCD about following wiring diagrams (especially the colors) and proper installation methods (cable clamps, protection, termination, etc.).   And view several YouTube videos, not just one.

Under current electrical code (in locations that tend to use 12/2 cable):

The circuit supplying the shed needs GFCI protection at its source
There should be a local disconnect where that cable enters the shed, before anything else. This can be a 20A switch, assuming that 12/2 wire means your breaker at the point of supply is 20A.
The outlets that are not switched should be wired with 12/2 from that point, with no interaction with the light switches or switched outlet for the light.
The switches need to be what is called "3-way" switches, and the wiring between them needs to be a 12/3 cable. The power source connects to one of the switches via 12/2, and the other switch connects to the switched outlet via 12/2 (there are other ways, but they are more complicated. Keep it simple.)
This means you'll have both a 12/2 cable for the outlets and a 12/3 cable for the switches running between the doorways.

Here is a 3-way wired as I suggest, because it's the simplest way for an inexperienced persion to wire one, in my opinion. Note the black screw and two brass screws on each switch. The diagram is a bit imperfect as it neglects grounds - all grounds connect to each other and to the box, if that is metallic. The green screw on switches and fixtures is for ground.

Image source
I would also echo the concerns expressed in comments that you appear to be operating somewhat out of your depth on this project. While you can certainly learn to do simple wiring, you can also be hurt, killed, or burn down your shed if you go at it without bothering to learn, first. Learning when to stop work and hit the library or call in a professional to help is an important part of learning to do things yourself.
